# atajo para insertar etiqueta dentro de una seleccion de etiquetas html

Tags: html, css, vscode, vim, emmet

Hola busco un atajo que me permita agregar una etiqueta, como padre de otras etiquetas
supongamos que tengo un código así.

```
<div class="contenedor">
    <div class="caja-1"></div>
</div>
```

entonces selecciono las etiquetas e inserto un div mas como padre del contenedor de forma automática, quedaría así.

```
<div>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="caja-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

simplemente busco un atajo para agregar una etiqueta dentro de un parrafo de etiquetas sin tener que hacerlo de forma manual.

actualmente uso vscode con el plugin emmet, aunque tambien uso vim con el mismo plugin, cualquier respuesta con vim o vscode me sirven, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te recomendaría leer [ask], no entiendo cual es el problema

Comment: hola, disculpa si no se entiendo mi pregunta, simplemente busco un atajo para poder escribir etiquetas dentro de otras etiquetas ya escritas, sin tener que escribirlo manualmente

Comment: A que llamas `atajo`? y desde donde quieres hacer ese `atajo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está extensión soluciona tu problema:

HTML Tag Wrapper:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hwencc.html-tag-wrapper

Después de instalarla y que esté operable seleccionas el texto, presionas Ctrl+i y te lo encierra en un div

Comment: gracias es lo que buscaba